# universal application retina image performace on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, retina-display, ios-universal-app

For universal application if only ipad retina images are used , then would thier be a performace degrade for iphone ? since iphone would be using same images , just UIImageview would be scaling it according to screen size .

Regards

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating images for a universal app, let's say you created a image called 'example'.

You should save the following:

- example~iphone.png -> this is for non retina iPhone
- example~iphone@2x.png -> this is for retina iPhone
- example~ipad.png -> this is for non retina iPad
- example~ipad@2x.png -> this is for retina iPad

So, doesn't matter from where you call it, you just call it this way, assuming myImageView is a UIImageView object:

`[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"example"]];`

The OS takes care of finding the correct image for the desired device.

Answer (score 1):

Performance shouldn't degrade substantially (or, even, noticeably in most cases). However, image quality may.

Assuming a 100px squa Retina iPad image, this will be scaled to 50% on a non-retina iPad (50px square) and it will probably look pretty good. However, unless you design your iPhone interface to use images that have a similarly simple scaling, you may find that `UIImageView`'s scaling (or `UIButton`'s or...) is less elegant that you would like.

You can use tricks to minimise this (the sort of things covered by the Thomas Fuchs's book at http://retinafy.me/) but image quality *won't* be as good as it will if you serve optimised images for each device and resolution.